# Boost asio ssl: password callback not called if private key passed with context::use_private_key

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, boost-asio

I'm writing a test unit that uses the boost asio ssl.

I'm using Boost 1.54 on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

I plan to make the test self-sufficient and not rely on files to specify the private key, so I want to hard encode the key and its password in the test itself (they are just test key and password).

The code is below. For now it does nothing but I'm just trying to make the password callback work when the private key is specified:

```
std::string password_callback(
  std::size_t max_length,
  boost::asio::ssl::context::password_purpose purpose)
{
    return "test";
}

TEST(StreamReader, sslStream)
{

    std::string certificate = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n\
MIIFJjCCAw4CCQDQjrFrRcdRkjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBVMQswCQYDVQQGEwJT\n\
BLABLABLABLA";

    std::string key = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n\
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED\n\
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,06622C22CAB27AC2\n\
\n\
JMudxXy4ZxB733xh7QO4elsVCTzJZuWl9Go4ZMuWx0DZb2fYHqXynKZSf7UactSw\n\
vhKJnLPZaa5U+xOr9cdpSd3SwtQyNu6yaVQH3af2ILRwUsw9mQmI8yqIIF1Y6AgV\n\
BLABLABLABLA";

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12);
    ctx.set_password_callback(password_callback);
    ctx.use_certificate(boost::asio::const_buffer(certificate.c_str(), certificate.size()), boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
    ctx.use_private_key(boost::asio::const_buffer(key.c_str(), key.size()), boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
    ctx.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
}
```

When `use_private_key` is executed then the password callback is not called and I have to enter the password manually in the console. If I replace `use_private_key` with `use_private_key_file` then the callback is called.

I would expect `password_callback` to be called also when `use_private_key` is used.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This reflects a limitation of the underlying OpenSSL API:

Encyption applies to loading keys from file only:

> The private keys loaded from file can be encrypted. In order to successfully load encrypted keys, a function returning the passphrase must have been supplied, see ssl_ctx_set_default_passwd_cb(3). (Certificate files might be encrypted as well from the technical point of view, it however does not make sense as the data in the certificate is considered public anyway.)

(from [ssl_ctx_use_privatekey_file](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ssl_ctx_use_privatekey_file))

Consider using the *raw* key from inside the application. The raw key should be difficult to spot from looking at a binary. Of course you can scatter the key around in bits and encrypt them manually, but keep in mind a determined attacker can always figure it out anyways.

The rationale behind this could be that passphrase protected key files can be passed around safely, as long as the passphrase is not passed at the same time. As soon as you embed the key in the program that also contains the passphrase used to decrypt it, passing it around is inherently unsafe anyways.

**UPDATE**

In fact it should not be difficult to get the desired behaviour by patching Boost Asio: The `use_private_key` context member function ends up calling `::PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey` which **[does support a password callback](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pem_read_bio_privatekey)**.

You could add it:

```
  //evp_private_key.p = ::PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(bio.p, 0, 0, 0);
  evp_private_key.p = ::PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(bio.p, 0, 
          handle_->default_passwd_callback,
          handle_->default_passwd_callback_userdata); // SEHE WAS HERE
```

to get the behaviour you want.

Be sure to ping the Asio developer/boost mailing lists whether they're interested in adding this as a feature.

Comment: I'm going to use the key and pwd in a test unit: the key is useless outside of the test so I'm not worried about embedding it in the code. Actually now I'm checking the internal of boost:asio::context and I see that the code calls PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey which also accepts a callback or passphrase as parameter but they are left null. I suspect this may be considered a bug in boost

Comment: I think my edit and your comment crossed. I've just tried with those params added and it does work as intended. I'd certainly take this up with the boost devs, as I already mentioned in the answer. Cheers

Comment: Reported as bug https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10828 (I'm trying to clean up the markdown in the report now ...)

Comment: 2023 nearly and this issue remains :)

Answer (score 0):

I have to update this thread because I was in the same situation. It seems that support for this is now implemented:

https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/a2204b67f85cf63936a1daaacee830b6b69cec9f/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp#L845

So good news!